# C# Outlook Addin - Context Menu Disposal

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin

We setup a custom context menu when you right click an email in Outlook like so:

```
        private void _application_ItemContextMenuDisplay(Office.CommandBar CommandBar, Interop.Selection Selection)
        {
                var contextButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)CommandBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Temporary: true);
                contextButton.Visible = true;
                contextButton.Caption = "&My Context Menu";
                contextButton.Click += MyContextMenu_Click;
        }
```

This method is subscribed to `Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay`.

It's working fine, except that occasionally our event gets fired multiple times.  It happens when you right-click quickly on different emails.

Then it makes me wonder, when is a good place to cleanup my temporary context menu item?  I need to unsubscribe the C# event somewhere.  Where is the intended place to do that?  (I would also think we might need to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`)

We are using VSTO and the Outlook 2010 project template in Visual Studio.  I haven't found many good examples of customizing the context menu, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quirkiness is probably why in Outlook 2010, Microsoft is moving more towards the [Ribbon XML context menu customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832.aspx) in favor of the Outlook 2007-style of `CommandBars`. See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882718/175679).

As for cleaning up resources used by the `CommandBars`, you would need to attach to the [`Application.ContextMenuClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175108%28v=office.12%29.aspx) event to free up resources and unsubscribe your listener. See [related SO post on disposing Outlook Context Menus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936841/175679).

You should refactor your code to utilize the newer Ribbon XML interface to avoid `CommandBars`.

Comment: We found that this event didn't get fired as expected (I think because it is the menu on a contact or email in a list).  I am not working on this issue anymore--we ended up cleaned up the old menu at the beginning of `ItemContextMenuDisplay`.  This worked great for us.