# Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010 to add to the Right Click menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, add-in, outlook-2010

How can I extend that menu when I open Email and Right Click on the body menu? I want to add some features.

[image: Right Click Email Body Menu]

I checked this Microsoft Developer Network Technical Article [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172.aspx) and could not get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 you may need access to the [`WordEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._inspector.wordeditor.aspx) from the active Outlook Inspector. See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/a7347989-926a-426c-ae6f-e51f73a2de64) regarding how to get access to the `WordEditor` from the [active inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.activeinspector.aspx).

You will need to work within the [Fluent Ribbon UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to [create context menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832.aspx). You just need to implement the [`IRibbonExtensibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433868.aspx) interface. The Ribbon UI uses XML to construct UI elements and handle events. [`CommandBars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206962%28v=office.12%29.aspx) have been [deprecated in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865324.aspx).